# Sequences of Normed Linear spaces

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Show the following

[1]

Show that closure of a convex subset of a norm space is a convex set.

**Solution**:

Let C be convex subset of normal space N and $x,y \in \overline{C}$

Then there exists a sequence {$x_{n}$} and {$y_{n}$} in C such that

$x_{n} \longrightarrow x$  and  $y_{n} \longrightarrow y$

For $ \alpha \in [0,1]$

$\alpha x_{n} + (1- \alpha)y_{n} \in C$

Since Addition and scalar multiplication is continuous so

$\alpha x_{n} + (1- \alpha)y_{n} \longrightarrow \alpha x + (1- \alpha) \in \overline{C}$

$\overline{C}$ is convex in N

$\blacksquare$

[2] Let C be a closed set in a normed linear space $\Big($$X , ||.||$ $\Big)$ over $\mathbb{F}$ , and let ($x_{n}$) be a sequence contained in C such that $\displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty} ~ x_{n} = x \in X$.

Then $x \in C$

I'm drawing a blank and I'm not sure what I'm supposed to do here. Do I have to take an epsilon delta definition and go from there? Or somehow get a convergent sequence and show that it converges?

Can someone help here?

Comment: How's a closed set defined in your textbook?

Comment: A subset S of a normed linear space $\Big( X ,||.|| \Big)$ is **open** if for each $s \in S$ there is an $\epsilon > 0$ such that $B(s , \epsilon) \subset S$

.A subset $F$ of a normed linear space $\Big( X ,||.|| \Big)$ is **closed** if its compliment $X/F$ is open. @ThomasShelby

Comment: Okay. So assume that  $x\notin C $. Then we can find an epsilon ball around  $x $ having empty intersection with  $C $. But $x_n\to x $. So....

Comment: Since $(x_{n})$ is a sequence in the open ball let $\epsilon > 0$ be given.

Now we have that there exists an element say $x \in$ the open ball $B$ such that $|| x_{n} - x||_{\infty} \longrightarrow 0$ as $n \longrightarrow \infty$ 

Now since $x_{n}$ is a sequence in the open ball there exists a N$\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $||x_{n} -x ||_{\infty} < \epsilon$ ? 

I'm trying to play around with this but i'm not getting anywhere. 

Are there any more hints you can give? @ThomasShelby

Comment: Since $x_n$ converges to $x $, every open ball around $x $ contains infinitely many elements of $(x_n) $. Now all of the $x_n $'s are from $C $. Can you connect this and the previous hint and write a proof by contradiction? And please consider posting it as an answer. If you ping me, I will verify your proof.